# How to import data to a specified tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My version of oracle is 11g. I had imported my oracle database to a SQL file called "**export.sql**". Two days back I reinstalled my machine with windows and reinstalled Oracle also. Now I have created a user named "book" with password "book" and have given privileges using this command:

```
grant create session, create table to book;
```

Then I tried to import my SQL file using SQL Developer utility, by opening the **export.sql** file in the SQL editor. Then it showed me that

```
SQL Error: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'USERS'
```

Then I thought it would be better to create a different tablespace rather than using the USERS table space. Then I created the tablespace "kwa" using this:

```
create tablespace kwa
logging
datafile 'G:\kwa\kwa.dbf' 
size 32m 
autoextend on 
next 32m maxsize 2048m
extent management local;
```

After this I have given privileges to user on that tablespace using this command:

```
alter user book quota 32m on kwa;
```

What I want to do now is to make the user "book" use that tablespace in SQL Developer so that I can import my "**export.sql**" ? , but still when I try to import data it is showing the old "**ORA-01950**" error. How to change the tablespace for the **user "book"** in the *SQLDeveloper interface* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
alter user book default tablespace kwa;
```

Whether this works depends on whether the **export.sql** references the *USERS* tablespace explicitly or not - if it does reference it then you will need to change **export.sql** !