# SQL Developer - No readers registered for SQL type error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle 11g. I had exported data using the installed version of SQL Developer to a sql file called "export.sql".  Now, I have downloaded the new version which is 3.1.07 and when I try to import data by clicking on the tree view and choosing Tables | Import Data and navigating to "export.sql", I get the following error:

> **no readers are registered for the sql type**

When I first started the application it asked for the path to java.exe and I have shown that path and application started. I have the started the application from the path where it was downloaded (**C:\users\kaushik\Downloads\sqldeveloper**)

Comment: Exactly what are you doing when you "try to import data from the sql file"?  Are you trying to open the file in SQL Developer (i.e. File | Open)?  Are you trying to run the file after opening it successfully?  Or something else?  Have you opened the file in a text editor to verify that it appears to be a valid SQL script?

Comment: @Justin Cave, I have opened the "sql" file in a text editor and found out that it is a valid sql file. I logged in using the username as book and password as book then right clicked on the tree view Tables->Import Data, and then selected the "export.sql' file, then it showed the error. My Oracle configuration is specified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467814/how-to-import-data-to-a-specified-tablespace

Answer (score 16):

You can call the file directly from sql developer.

Example: If you saved you file to c:\Oracle\MyBackups\Export.sql
Then from within Sql Developer, connect to your database and use the sql command:

@C:\Oracle\MyBackups\Export.sql

and that will execute the Export.Sql script.

Comment: Martin Jones, you are great man! Thank you very much for the hint.

Comment: Working fine ,using script output we can see the log, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have a valid SQL file, you simply need to execute the script.  Open the file (File | Open and navigate to export.sql), hit the Run Script button (F5 on Windows), and choose the connection you want to use.  The Data Import Wizard supports a number of different file formats (Excel, CSV, etc.).  It doesn't support SQL files.  If you want to ask the developers why they don't support SQL (or why they use the general file navigation dialog rather than using different dialogs for different sorts of files) you can ask them over in the [SQL Developer forum on OTN](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=260).  I assume the problem is that most SQL scripts contain much more than simple `INSERT` statements and it would be challenging to figure out whether any particular script was actually just a bunch of `INSERT` statements that could be used to import data.
2. Yes, SQL Developer is written in Java so you need to have an appropriate version of the JVM installed.  Different SQL Developer download options include a bundled JVM or you can download a smaller file and use an already installed JVM.

Comment: I have already run the SQL file. I am wondering why there is an "import data" option if it cannot be used. I downloaded this new version of SQLDeveloper this morning to get this functionality.

Comment: @kaushik - The Data Import Wizard supports a few different file formats (Excel, CSV, etc.).  It doesn't support SQL scripts most likely because most SQL scripts contain much more than simple `INSERT` statements.  I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

One of oracle client tools to make session to database is sqlDeveloper and its graphical interface tool Programmed with **Java Lang**  and its installed independently from oracle_home its a stand alone product and Of Course it needs SDK Or JDK to work
make sure to set the path and check it 
read this link http://www.ehow.com/how_5127784_set-java-path.html

all of this if sql developer didn't run and other similar problem
this to answer

***Is JDK is needed or what ?*** Yes

Comment: Has anyone really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like?

Comment: i dont understand your comment !?

Answer (score 0):

use sql Developer higher version
i am upgraded to Version 20.2.0.175
issue resolved